# Can you claim P(B|C) >= P(B|A,C) for a Bayseian network of the graphical model "A-->C; B->C"?

Tags: probability, bayesian, graphical-model

Consider a Bayesian network

[image]

where A and B are independent. Intuitively,  since both A and B can influence C, the probability of B given C should drop if A is observed.

### Question

Does

$$P(B|C)\geq P(B|A,C) $$

systematically hold for this sort of Bayesian Network? Can we prove it, or otherwise, find a counter-example?

Answer (score 1):

In your graphical model, $A, B, C$ are random variables so what you are asserting is
$$
P(B=b\mid C=c)\ge P(B=b\mid A=a,C=c)\tag1
$$
for all choices of $a,b,c$. But this doesn't necessarily hold.

A counterexample: Let $A$ and $B$ be independent Bernoulli($1/2$) variables, so each one takes value $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. Let $C$ be the indicator that $A=B$. Then the joint distribution of $(A,B,C)$ follows your graphical model, taking the four values $(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,1)$ with equal probability $1/4$. You can calculate that
$$
P(B=0\mid C=0)=\frac{P(100)}{P(010)+P(100)}=\frac12\tag2
$$
$$
P(B=0\mid A=0, C=0)=\frac{P(000)}{P(010)}=0\tag3
$$
$$
P(B=0\mid A=1, C=0)=\frac{P(100)}{P(100)}=1\tag4
$$
We see that calculations (2) and (3) satisfy inequality (1), but with (2)
 and (4) the inequality (1) is strict in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks. A bit confused about your first paragraph: Did you say my claim is true but meanwhile, "it doesn't necessarily hold"?

Comment: @zell Ambiguous syntax on my part. I should replace "asserting is true" by "asserting" (which I just did).